# Titanium Alloy - how to persist model singleton?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

*runs in iOs & Android

coffeeScript*

I have a model such as:

```
    exports.definition =
        config:
            columns:
                cookie: "string"
            defaults:
                cookie: ""
            adapter:
                # is this valid?
                type: "sql"
                collection_name: "userInfo"
        extendModel: (Model) ->
            _.extend Model::,
                isSignedIn:->
                    this.get('cookie').length > 0
            Model
```

And a index.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <Model id="userInfo" src="userInfo" instance="true"/>
```

So, this `userInfo` properties change during the lifecycle of the app, the user logs in, and I want to keep that cookie being persisted as well as auto-loaded on app init.

How do I do that in this framework?

**UPDATE another Q&A**
For reference here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/147601/alloy---persist-and-load-a-singleton-model#255723

Answer (score 3):

They don't explain it well in the appcelerator docs, but if you want to store and retreive properties using build-in alloy properties sync adapter you have to specify a unique "id" when  using models. You did it already in the xml markup: `<Model id="userInfo"` but that will work for that view file only. If you want to access/update this property in the controller you do this:

```
var UserInfo = Alloy.createModel("userInfo", {id: "userInfo"});
UserInfo.fetch();
UserInfo.set("cookie", "new value");
UserInfo.save();
```

If you want to keep the reference to this property thruout the code, I believe, you just attach it to the global namespace in the alloy.js:

```
var UserInfo = Alloy.createModel("userInfo", {id: "userInfo"});
UserInfo.fetch();
Alloy.Globals.UserInfo = UserInfo;
```

In the controllers you do:

```
var UserInfo = Alloy.Globals.UserInfo;
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your model `userInfo.js` into `app/model`, it will probably look like this:

```
exports.definition = {

    config : {
        "columns" : {
            "cookie" : "string"
        },
        "defaults" : { "cookie" : "" }
        "adapter" : {
            "type" : "sql",
            "collection_name" : "userInfo"
        }
    },

    extendModel : function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            isSignedIn : function() {
                this.get('cookie').length > 0
            }
        });
        return Model;
    },

    extendCollection : function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
        });
        return Collection;
    }
}
```

From here it depends on what you want to do, but you can easily fetch the model from the collection `userInfo`, just put this: `<Collection src="userInfo"/>` in your xml file.

As a side note, I usually just use the [`Titanium.App.Properties`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties) stuff to store user information. Properties are used for storing application-related data in property/value pairs that persist beyond application sessions and device power cycles. For example:

```
// Returns the object if it exists, or null if it does not
var lastLoginUserInfo = Ti.App.Properties.getObject('userInfo', null);
if(lastLoginUserInfo === null) {
    var userInfo = {cookie : "Whatever the cookie is", id : "123456789"};
    Ti.App.Properties.setObject('userInfo', userInfo);
} else {
   // Show the cookie value of user info
   alert(lastLoginUserInfo.cookie);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will keep in mind `Ti.App.Properties`, Alloy models has an adapter that responds by 'properties'

Comment: Yes, but I find that its just easier to use Ti.App.properties instead of the adapter, especially for singleton models, whats the point of using sql if you only have one.